# How to index filenames along with text in file on Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, solr4

I indexed word documents in Solr. But When i query with search text , then returning xml file contains searched text but no the name of the file which contains the text,.

For Ex:

Let the word document `Printer.doc` & `models.doc` contains the word `HP`.

When I give `HP` as query word , the returning XML response must have tags as

```
<doc>
<str name="filename" >Printer.doc </str>
<str name ="filename" >models.doc</str>
```

How to ahive this..

I use follwing command to upload and index document

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=1 -Dtype=application/word -jar post.jar *.doc
```

Please tell me how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mapping *stream_name* to a field?

Otherwise, create a dynamic field and [map all the tika metadata fields to that prefix](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Input_Parameters). One of the metadata fields should be file name. Then, you can remap it to whatever you want.